# How can I apply overloading method Using Picture in Scala?

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I have lists of strings and i wanted to make the program look more presentable using the Picture library. The problem is that the it's asking for overloading method, and as I am new to Scala I don't have any clue, on implementing the overloading method.

```
val r = Picture("**********\n**********")
val s = Picture("++++\n++++\n++++\n++++\n++++\n++++")
val t = Picture("o\no\no\no")
val u = Picture("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%")
val keywords = List(Picture("abstract","case", "catch", "class", 
     "def", "do", "else", "extends", "false", "final", "finally", 
     "for", "forSome", "if", "implicit", "import", "lazy","match", "new", "Null",
     "object", "override", "package", "private", "protected", "return","sealed", "super",
     "this", "throw","trait", "Try", "true", "type", "val", "Var", "while", "with", "yield"))
println(spread(keywords,TOP).frame)

//val keywords = List(Picture())
```

the word "Picture" gives me error as it says it requires overloading method

Comment: Looking at you past few questions, it seem that you are learning Scala. But if you are still describing the thing as the `"word" Picture` then I will really suggest you to change your way of learning. Please refer a to a good Scala book. There is an awesome book for absolute beginners by underscore.io - https://underscore.io/training/courses/essential-scala/ and it is free. If you really want to learn Scala, do it properly. There is no point in asking such questions on stack-over-flow

Comment: thank you sir, this books is so much helpful, I have completed the overloading method. Still I could not find "Picture" in the book but it gave me an idea ` val r = Picture("Keyword\t")   val p3 = Picture("")` ` val p7 = List(p3) ` and it works.